# How to make optmizied SQL query to retrieve a number of records in each timeslice group

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

I am using for this project Postgress database but this question can be applied on any database.

I need to make more efficient the selection of records from database.
I have a table Activity containing records for each activity being registered on the system.

The table Activity consist of the following columns

```
id             integer 
time_stamp     time stamp without timezone
computer_id    varchar(255)
user_id        varchar(255)
...
```

In general I require a simple results.
I need to be able to specify time slices of 5 minutes or any other period.
And need to find out if there is any record in each time slice. So in the end I need a True or False result per each time slice.

I need to color a table with a color if the there is True or leave it blank for False.

I made a program solution that is going through do while loop and selects a number of records for each time slice.

For example:

```
select *
from Activity
where time_stamp between prev_Time and curr_Time
```

This works but is very slow. If the time slice is 5 min then there is 24h x 60min / 5 min = 288 select querys.

I need to find a way to make one fast select query. I can't make stored procedures.
And even better do not know how to write in SQL to give me all time periods from start time to end time in groups of 5 min.

Any solution even in code is acceptable but must be fast. The response must be in max 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [generate_series()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) function to create intervals, something like this:

```
select g, count(a.id)
from generate_series(
    '20131017 07:00'::timestamp,
    '20131017 08:00'::timestamp,
    '5 minutes'::interval
) as g
   left outer join Activity as a on
      a.time_stamp >= g and a.time_stamp < g + '5 minutes'::interval
group by g
order by g
```

If you don't need to have records where count = 0, you can use this query:

```
with cte as (
    select
        (extract(epoch from time_stamp - '20131017 07:00'::timestamp) / 60)::int / 5 as p
    from Activity
    where time_stamp <= '20131017 08:00'::timestamp  
)
select
    '20131017 07:00'::timestamp + ((p * 5)::text || ' minutes')::interval, count(*)
from cte
group by p
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/33816/14)</kbd>**